# PHP Trouble with day change

Tags: php, date

I have this code bellow it works fine but when the time hits 24 till 1 it doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

The code I have:

```
<?php
$h = date('G'); //set variable $h to the hour of the day
$d = date('w'); //set variable $d to the day of the week.
$year = date('Y'); //set variable $year to the current year
//G is the date key for hours in 24 format (not 12), with no leading 0s, like 02.
// MONDAY SCHEDULE
if ($d == 1 && $h >= 0 && $h < 4) $text= 'bob';
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 22 && $h < 23) $text= 'adam';
else if ($d == 1 && $h >= 23 && $h < 24) $text= 'tina';
else if ($d == 2 && $h < 0) $img = 'mark';
// TUESDAY SCHEDULE
if ($d == 2 && $h >= 0 && $h < 4) $text= 'alex';
else if ($d == 2 && $h >= 4 && $h < 8) $text= 'jason';
else if ($d == 3 && $h < 0) $text= 'gorge';
print $text;
?>
```

When it's mark's or gorge's turns it doesn't work. I would like to know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Wow. Why aren't you using DateTime() and saving yourself some pain?

Comment: But I want the names to change every hour

Comment: Based on your response I'm guessing you have no idea what DateTime() even is.

Comment: It doesn't work because `$h` (hour) cannot be less than 0?

Comment: haha to be honest I'm not experienced with php. If you can please guide me that would be really appreciated

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want the names to change every hour. If it's possible to have all the names in a test file and the php reads every line each hour that would be great.

Comment: I think [matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5641619/matt) has the right idea. When you use the G flag for hour, valid values are 0-23. The mark case for Monday will never show because the hour is never less than 0. The Tina case for Monday can just be $h == 23, because it cannot be greater than 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in comments, the test on `$h < 0` will always return false, as *$h* is an integer between 0 and 23.

But you could make your schedule more readable and manageable if you would create a data structure for it, like this:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$persons = array(
    '-' => '(no one)',
    'a' => 'Bob',
    'b' => 'Adam',
    'c' => 'Tina',
    'd' => 'Marc',
    'e' => 'Alex',
    'f' => 'Jason',
    'g' => 'George'
);
$schedule = array(
//   012345678901234567890123
    '------------------------', // Sunday
    'aaaa------------------bc', // Monday
    'eeeeffff----------------', // Tuesday
    '------------------------', // Wednesday
    '------------------------', // Thursday
    '------------------------', // Friday
    '------------------------', // Saturday
);

// Use mb_substr to support multi-byte characters (unicode)    
print $persons[mb_substr($schedule[date('w')],date('G'),1)];
```

In the above code, each person gets a unique letter. That letter is used in a kind of grid, where each row represents a weekday, and each column (character position) an hour of the day (0-23).

This way you have a rather visual representation, which might be easier to manage. And as it turns out, to get the person that is scheduled for the current hour-slot just takes a single line of code.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if I have more then 160 people. I mean a different person each hour but that person appears once a week. 23x7=161. There isn't 161 letters. What should I do in that case? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: They don't have to be letters, and can be any character. Unicode offers over 60000 characters.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just avoid quote and backslash characters, because you would need to escape those, which destroys the nice layout. Also don't use hyphen, because I gave it the special meaning (no-one). But you can use uppercase and lowercase (they are regarded as different), accented letters, punctuation, greek letters, cyrillic letters, ...etc.

Comment: I just tested it with different Unicode like Greek and Cyrillic but it gives me: Undefined index: � here is and example: 'ҿӁӈӋӐӕәΈΊΌΎΏΐΔΘΞΣΩΨάθϾϷϰ', // Saturday

Comment: Yes, but you need to define the corresponding person in the `$persons` table, with an entry like `"Ӌ" => "Peter",`.

Comment: Is it because I'm using xampp to test it or it shouldn't matter

Comment: No, I updated the code to force UTF-8 character encoding, and to extract characters as such. So there is an extra line at the start of the script, and the last line changed.